# Error in wiki tutorial template. <Table of content> macro doesn't include <TutorialCSHeaderTemplate> Header

Tags: ros, tutorial, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm currently writing a tutorial and  i've found that in template given, there are two macros in this order:

<< IncludeCSTemplate(TutorialCSHeaderTemplate)>>
<< TableOfContents(5)>>

The first one, adds a header (with number '1.'), then in my content I add another header and this is indexed as '2.', but in the table of contents, it starts counting from my header as '1.' and so on.

Reading about macros, I think this is due to << IncludeCSTemplate() >> doesn't set 'generates_headings' to True in order to be included in Table of contents.

A solution could be to write a new template setting this parameter to true, but I think would be better to correct this issue in the existent macro, if this is the problem.

Anyone have another solution to this?

---

Edit:

@dornhege As you said, the template creates a header, description, level, notes, etc... But that header starts as '1. templateHeader' and next headers will be '2. myHeaderBla', '3.AnotherHeaderFoo'.

But in the Table of Contents template, the header generated by the HeaderTemplate does not appear. Instead of this, the numeration starts with '1.myHeaderBla', '2.AnotherHeaderFoo'. This is just a issue of page view.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49256/error-in-wiki-tutorial-template.-%3Ctable-of-content%3E-macro-doesn%27t-include-%3Ctutorialcsheadertemplate%3E-header/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-11-27**:
I see, what you mean. That seems wrong.  When using Level 3 headers (===), the TOC seems to strip the higher level an numerates the subsections 1.1, 1.2 as 1, 2. Maybe this is the intended usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not really sure, what you want to achieve, but if you just want the headings in the tutorial to look nice, use the `== section blah ==` syntax.

The template creates the tutorial header with description, tutorial level, etc. Do you want multiple of those in one tutorial?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0